# A doubt regarding the formulation of a theorem in Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis".

Tags: real-analysis

The following assertion appears in Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis"

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions (for $n=1,2,3\dots$). For $x\in X$, put $$g(x)=\sup f_n(x)$$ $$h(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup f_n(x)$$

What is the difference between $g(x)$ and $h(x)$? I suppose $g(x)$ is the supremum of the set $\{f_1(x),f_2(x)\dots\}$ for every $x\in X$. What is $h(x)$ then?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}$ then for $x \in X$ we have
$$
\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n(x) = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n} = 1
$$
but certainly we have $f_n(x) \to 0 \; \forall x \in X$ as $n \to \infty$ so we have $\limsup_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$.

I'm guessing the issue arises from not remembering that
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}, k \ge n} a_k
$$
so, in qualitative terms, we are only looking at the $\sup$ for *big* $n$ in the $\limsup$ as opposed to over all $n$ for the general $\sup$.

Comment: OK didn't know that. Thanks a lot.